# Trim method and .length() Javascript

Tags: javascript, trim, string-length

I'm doing the Magpie Chatbot AP Computer Science Lab, and I'm trying to determine whether the user is typing a message or just putting a space and pressing return using the .trim() method. The code is:

```
    String response = "";
    statement= statement.trim();
    if(statement.length() < 0)
    {
        response = "Please say something :)";
    }
```

statement is the user inputted statement, response is what the chatbot outputs. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: That doesn't look like JavaScript... what exactly is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: A string is unlikely to have a length *less than* 0 ... Presumably you want `statement.length() == 0` (`length` is more often than not a property rather than a `method()`)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting MDN's documentation for [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length): *The length property represents the length of a string.*

`length` is a property and not a method.